# How do you fill in or bypass HTTP Basic Auth in Rails 5.2 System Tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, automated-tests, capybara

I'm writing some tests for a site that is protected with http authentication on all pages.

I've managed to come across a way of bypassing it for controller tests by doing the following

`get exams_url, headers: {'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials('admin','admin') }`

But how do I get past it for a system test? I've been searching around for hours to try and find a solution for this, but all of the suggestions I've found appear to be for older versions of Rails/Capybara and do not work. There doesn't appear to be anything in the Rails testing documentation regarding this either.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, this seems to do the trick for me

```
def visit_with_http_auth(path)
  username = 'admin'
  password = 'admin'
  visit "http://#{username}:#{password}@#{Capybara.current_session.server.host}:# 
  {Capybara.current_session.server.port}#{path}"
end
```

And then in my test methods I just do

```
test "visiting the index" do
  visit_with_http_auth questions_path
  assert_selector "h1", text: "Questions"
end
```

Comment: I edited to replace `Capybara.current_session` with `page`

Answer (score 1):

There’s no need to mess with Capybara. Just add this method to `ActiveSupport::TestCase` in your `test_helper.rb`:

```
def visit_authenticated(url)
  uri = URI.parse(url)
  uri.user = 'put_your_user_here'
  uri.password = 'put_your_password_here'
  visit uri
end
```